# xpages pass a value from smartcard without using url parameter

Tags: xpages, smartcard, url-parameters

When an xpage is loaded into the browser, it checks to see if the the referrer contains  the string "TranslateForm".

```
return facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getHeader("Referer");
```

If it doesn't contain my string, it redirects to the URL "Home?RequestCert&SubmitCert&TranslateForm=CertSubmitTranslation" and then redirects to the xpage where it passes the initial test. I can easily get info from that Home form which captures info from the smart card (e.g. CommonName) and then pass it as a URL Parameter by appending the string "?CN=" + document.forms[0].CommonName.value

Then, I can obviously capture that appended value and do what I want with it as I process the xpage. 
What I want to do is capture that CommonName field and save it in the backend without using a URL Parameter. I don't want the user to be able to see it or look in the source for a hidden field.

Comment: use POST instead of GET - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: What kind of SmartCard do you use and how does it make its values available in the browser. And yes - Frantisek points to the right approach: POST

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "type of smart card", but the way I make values available in the browser is to use the form Submitted Certificate Translation form to parse data from the card. How and where do I change from POST to GET in the xpage?

Comment: A browser is a piece of software, a smartcard a piece of hardware, somehow they need to communicate.That part is usually done by a hardware specific driver, hence my question: what card. When XPages shows a form it usually is POST, unless you created your own HTML form, then check the form element and set the attribute "method" to POST

Comment: Users have an external card reader, it is built into their laptop, or built into their keyboard. "ActivClient" is the software/driver by the company ActivIdentity. All that works. I can get any info I want from the smartcard by using the Translation form. Right now, the only way I know to pass that info onto a new instance of an xpage is to go to use 
   document.location = "/path/db.nsf/xpage.xsp&CN=" + document.forms[0].CommonName.value;

Then I can grab whatever that value is on the xpage and save use it on processing, save it to the document in the backend, etc.

Comment: I want to load up a new xpage and save the value of that field w/o using a URL Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. What I did to solve this problem was to use the URL Parameter when launching the page:

```
document.location = "/path/db.nsf/xpage.xsp?CN=" + document.forms[0].CommonName.value;
```

AND I created a Counter field with a value of 0.

Then, in the BeforePageLoad event of the xpage, I ran a script to determine first if the Counter was at 0. If Counter was still at 0, then I tested if the URL had that parameter in it.
If so, I wrote that value to the backend document, incremented the Counter, and saved it.

```
document1.replaceItemValue("CI", context.getUrlParameter("CI"));
```

Then reloaded the xpage/document in Edit mode without the URL parameter.